# how to get part of date qweb odoo

Tags: odoo, qweb

The date in my Invoice is currently showing as:

> 21/11/2014 16:59:15

I want to show just month something like this:

> 11

I tried using t-esc with strftime but that doesn't work:

```
<span t-esc="o.date_order.strftime('%m')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
<span t-esc="datetime.datetime.strptime(o.sale_id.confirmation_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%B %d,%Y')"/>
```

My Output is: May 28,2018

Hope, It will be use.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question - the OP wants the month as a number for a start.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```xml
<span t-field="o.date_order" t-field-options='{"format": "MM"}'/>
```

More on [supported format patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).